# How to setup which libraries link in RelWithDebugInfo build configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I know how to link different libraries based on whether build configuration is `Debug` or `Release`. I use:

```
    foreach(dep ${DEPENDENCIES})
        target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME}
            debug ${dep}_d
            optimized ${dep}
        )
    endforeach(dep)
```

CMake by default create 4 build configurations in VS2010 (`Debug, Release, RelWithDebugInfo, MinSizeRelease`). But how to define taget link libraries for `RelWithDebugInfo` configuration?

***Bakcground:***
I use only `Debug`, `Release` and `RelWithDebugInfo`. My debug libraries have suffix `_d` and others have no suffix. So output files from `Release` and `RelWithDebugInfo` are the same. Sometimes when I build `RelWithDebugInfo` and then `Release` some output files are not overwritten and thus bad ones are loaded and program crashes. I want to solve this problem by adding some other suffix to `RelWithDebugInfo` configuration.

Comment: I do similar but I have not had any problem with that. Although depending on your situation you may be able to use imported targets. http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for your comment. I am not really sure if this is what I need. Could you please explain how to solve my problem with this in more detail? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It is impossible to do via `target_link_librearies` but it can be done by setting linker flags:

```
    set(DEBUG_DEP)
    set(RWD_DEP)
    set(RELEASE_DEP)

    foreach(dep ${DEPENDENCIES})
            set(RWD_DEP ${RWD_DEP} ${dep}_rwd)
            set(DEBUG_DEP ${DEBUG_DEP} ${dep}_d)
            set(RELEASE_DEP ${RELEASE_DEP} ${dep})
    endforeach(dep)

    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} " /LIBPATH:" ${DEBUG_DEP})
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} " /LIBPATH:" ${RELEASE_DEP})
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" /LIBPATH:" ${RWD_DEP})
```