# Visual studio doesn't overwrite output libraries for different build configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I use CMake generated solution for Visual Studio 2010.

In my solution I have several `lib` projects and one `exe` project. 
For `Debug` build configuration I use output names like `lib1_d.lib`, `lib2_d.lib` etc...

For `Release` build configuration I use `lib1.lib`, `lib2.lib` ...

thanks to CMake I have one extra build configuration I use - `RelWithDebugInfo`. I use same output names for this build configuration as for `Release`.

Now here is the problem:

Assuming everything is cleaned.

I hit `F5` (run / start debugging) `RelWithDebugInfo`. All project are built (`exe` is depending on them) and project runs successfully.

I switch to `Release` and hit `F5` again. All project are built and project runs successfully. (libraries in output directory are overwritten)

I switch back to `RelWithDebugInfo` and hit `F5`. VS quickly goes through and gives `All outputs are up-to-date.` ... `Build succeeded.` And DOES NOT overwrite `lib` files in output directory. So application crashes because it uses libraries for other build configuration.

This problem occurs for both ordering `Release->RelWithDebugInfo` and `RelWithDebugInfo->Release`

I haven't find a solution, how to add other prefix to `RelWithDebugLibraries` [my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895393/how-to-setup-which-libraries-link-in-relwithdebuginfo-build-configuration)

Is there a way, to force `Visual Studio 2010` to always overwrite outputs? Preferably by some flag which I can provide from CMake.

Comment: Are you putting more than 1 configuration in the same folder? Like Hans Passant said in his answer my Release and RelWithDebInfo files are in separate folders. And these are for CMake generated projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS build system solves this problem by using different build directories for different configurations.  By default, 32-bit Debug output goes to the Debug directory, Release output goes to the Release directory, 64-bit Debug output goes to x64\Debug directory, etcetera.  This way different configurations never step on each other's output files.

Looks to me like the mistake you made with your added RelwithDebugInfo configuration is that you didn't modify the output file names.  So the build system sees an up-to-date output file from *another* configuration and doesn't think it necessary to rebuild them.

Coming up with variations of build output file names does get to be impractical once you go past two, do consider the VS-way to do this.